# Why does trying to kill a process in Docker container take me out of it?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, docker, kubernetes

I have a v6.10.0 Node server on my macOS that is automatically started from the `CMD` in the `Dockerfile`. Normally in my local development un-containerized environment I will use CTRL+C to kill the server. Not being able to (or not knowing how to) do this in the container, I resort to `ps aux | grep node` to try to manually kill the processes. So, I get something like this:

```
myapp [master] :> kubectl exec -it web-3127363242-xb50k bash
root@web-3127363242-xb50k:/usr/src/app# ps aux | grep node
root        15  0.4  0.9 883000 35804 ?        Sl   05:49   0:00 node /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin/concurrent --kill-others npm run start-prod npm run start-prod-api
root        43  0.1  0.6 743636 25240 ?        Sl   05:49   0:00 node /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin/better-npm-run start-prod
root        44  0.1  0.6 743636 25140 ?        Sl   05:49   0:00 node /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin/better-npm-run start-prod-api
root        55  0.0  0.0   4356   740 ?        S    05:49   0:00 sh -c node ./bin/server.js
root        56  0.0  0.0   4356   820 ?        S    05:49   0:00 sh -c node ./bin/api.js
root        57 18.6  4.9 1018088 189416 ?      Sl   05:49   0:08 node ./bin/server.js
root        58 13.9  5.2 1343296 197576 ?      Sl   05:49   0:06 node ./bin/api.js
root        77  0.0  0.0  11128  1024 ?        S+   05:50   0:00 grep node
```

When I try to kill one of them by

```
kill -9 15
```

I am taken out of my container's shell and back to my computer's shell. When I enter the container again, I see that the process is still there with the same process id. This example uses a Kubernetes pod but I believe I have the same result with entering a Docker container using the `docker exec` command.

Comment: I think you kill command indirectly results in container restart. Try looking at `kubectl describe pod web-.....`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every docker container has an **ENTRYPOINT** that will either be set in the *dockerfile*, using `ENTRYPOINT`or `CMD` declarations, or specified in the run command `docker run myimage:tag "entrypoint_command"`. When the **ENTRYPOINT** process is killed, I think the container gets killed as well. The `docker exec`, as I understand it, is kind of like "attaching" command to a container. But if the **ENTRYPOINT** is down there is no container to attach to.

Kubernetes will restart a container after failure as far as I understand it. Which might be the reason you see the process is back up. I haven't really worked with Kubernetes but I'd try and play around with the way that the replications are [scaled](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/deployments/#scaling-a-deployment) to terminate your process.

Comment: In my case I wanted to kill the entry-point process and restart it, from inside the container. Switching `ENTRYPOINT` to `CMD` allowed this as `bash` becomes the "container-process" when running the container with `/bin/bash`.

Answer (score 4):

Containers isolate your desired app as pid 1 inside the namespace. The desired app being your entrypoint or cmd if you don't have an entrypoint defined. If killing a process results in pid 1 exiting, the container will immediately stop (similar to killing pid 1 on a linux host) along with killing all of the other pids. If this container has a restart policy, it will be restarted and the processes will get the same pids as last time it ran (all else being equal which it often is inside of a container).

To keep the container from stopping, you'll need to adjust your entrypoint to remain up even with the child process being killed. That side, having the container exit is typically a preferred behavior to handle unexpected errors by getting back to a clean state.